# How do I import a project containing AspectJ aspects and annotation in another project

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I'm having some difficulties importing a utility jar file containing some custom aspects into another project. It should be noted, that I'm *not* using Spring for this project, as my client is somewhat averse to Spring.

I have created a proof of concept (full code example below). When I run a test runner in the utility jar, any method annotated with my AspectJ annotation gets their aspects executed just fine. When I use the self-same jar in another project, the aspects are ignore.

When I run the main class in the utility I get:

```
$> java -cp aspectjrt-1.8.2.jar;aop-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar TestOne
AspectOne's aroundAdvice's body is now executed Before aspectTestMethod is called. 
Executing TestOne.aspectTestMethod() 
AspectOne's aroundAdvice's body is now executed After aspectTestMethod is called.
```

If I run the main class of the consumer class, I get:

```
$>java -cp aspectjrt-1.8.2.jar;aop-util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;aop-consumer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar Test
Test.testAspectOne
AspectTwo's aroundAdvice's body is now executed Before aspectTestMethod is called.
Test.testAspectTwo
AspectTwo's aroundAdvice's body is now executed After aspectTestMethod is called.
```

As I'm fairly new to aspect oriented programming, I'd really appreciate a pointer as to what I'm missing :)

## utility jar

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>sandbox.aop</groupId>
        <artifactId>aop-util</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

### Annotation

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface AnnotationOne { }
```

### Aspect

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.*;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;

@Aspect
public class AspectOne {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(AnnotationOne)")
    public void annotationPointCutDefinition(){
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
    public void atExecution(){}

    @Around("@annotation(AnnotationOne) && execution(* *(..))")
    public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object returnObject = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("AspectOne's aroundAdvice's body is now executed Before aspectTestMethod is called.");
            returnObject = joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throw throwable;
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("AspectOne's aroundAdvice's body is now executed After aspectTestMethod is called.");
        }
        return returnObject;
    }

    @After("annotationPointCutDefinition() && atExecution()")
    public void printNewLine(JoinPoint pointcut){
        System.out.print("\n\r");
    }
}
```

### Main class

```
public class TestOne {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestOne testOne = new TestOne();
        testOne.aspectTestMethod();
    }

    @AnnotationOne
    public void aspectTestMethod(){
        System.out.println("Executing TestOne.aspectTestMethod()");
    }
}
```

## AOP consumer

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sandbox.aop</groupId>
    <artifactId>aop-consumer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sandbox.aop</groupId>
            <artifactId>aop-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### Annotation

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface AnnotationTwo {}
```

### Aspect

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class AspectTwo {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(AnnotationTwo)")
    public void annotationPointCutDefinition(){
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
    public void atExecution(){}

    @Around("@annotation(AnnotationTwo) && execution(* *(..))")
    public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object returnObject = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("AspectTwo's aroundAdvice's body is now executed Before aspectTestMethod is called.");
            returnObject = joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throw throwable;
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("AspectTwo's aroundAdvice's body is now executed After aspectTestMethod is called.");
        }
        return returnObject;
    }

    @After("annotationPointCutDefinition() && atExecution()")
    public void printNewLine(JoinPoint pointcut){
        System.out.print("\n\r");
    }
}
```

### Main class

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.testAspectOne();
        test.testAspectTwo();
    }

    @AnnotationOne
    public void testAspectOne() {
        System.out.println(Test.class.getName() + ".testAspectOne");
    }

    @AnnotationTwo
    public void testAspectTwo() {
        System.out.println(Test.class.getName() + ".testAspectTwo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the aspectj weaver to weave aspect defined in your library using aspectLibraries:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
       <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>sandbox.aop</groupId>
                <artifactId>aop-util</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
       </aspectLibraries>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Brilliant. This worked. I'll mark this as the solution. Thanks a lot.